# Mail send from setting in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email-translation

I have a Magento store am trying out. When I signup as a user I received expected email. But the concern is that it shows the email sender server information like:

> ME me@mydomain.com via p3pl0129prod.phx.secureserver.net.
>   What can I do to remove the
>
> via p3pl0129prod.phx.secureserver.net from the sender info on email a user receives.

I have checked through the Admin area with no success. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you set the return path in system -> configuration -> advanced -> system -> Mail sending settings ?

Comment: Prateek. Yes what else can I do

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I know about this issue, maybe this can help a little : http://inchoo.net/magento/fight-spam-emails/

Comment: install / configure your own smtp server.